# How to show data that's not in a table. SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a data base with two tables.

```
Table Players               Table Wins
ID   Name                     ID    Player_won
1    Mick                     1        2
2    Frank                    2        1
3    Sarah                    3        4
4    Eva                      4        5
5    Joe                      5        1
```

I need a SQL query which show "The players who have not won any game".
I tried but I don't know even how to begin.
Thank you

Comment: `The players who have not won any game`. Your example data doesn't show any such players, making it extremely ambiguous as to how they are represented, or _would be_ represented. Does the "wins" tables _always_ have a row for every player, even if that player has no wins yet? In other words, is it possible for `Player_won` to be `0`, or is a player without wins _not represented_ in that table? [My answer[(https://stackoverflow.com/a/72510331/20789) should handle all the reasonable possibilities correctly, but you shoul drecognize why your problem statement is very ambiguous.

Comment: @DanLenski player 3 hasn't won any games: `Player_won` is (unsurprisingly) the id of the player that won.

Comment: @Bohemian, that's not how _I_ read the `wins` table, and the other answers reflect the same ‍♂️. I read the `wins` table as stating that player 3 has won 4 games (`id=3`, `player_won=4`). But your reading — that the `Wins.ID` is _not_ a foreign key to `Players.ID` — is also a plausible one. We need the OP to clarify _what these tables actually mean_.

Comment: @DanLenski it's crystal clear to me, especially if you reasonably assume that OP has provided example data to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Strongly disagree on this one, @bohemian. If the foreign key relationship between the tables is not explicitly specified, then multiple interpretations are possible.

Comment: @DanLenski - my reading is the ID on each table is the ID for that particular table, and that there should be a foreign key on WINS simlar to `ALTER TABLE WINS ADD CONSTRAINT WINS_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (PLAYER_WON) REFERENCES PLAYERS(ID)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need all the rows from `players` that don't have corresponding rows in `wins`. For this you need a *left* join, filtering for rows that *don't* join:

```
select
  p.id,
  p.name
from Players p
left join Wins w on w.Player_won = p.id
where w.Player_won is null
```

You can also use `not in`:

```
select
  id,
  name
from Players
where id not in (select Player_won from Wins)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the `MINUS` set operator?

Sample data:

```
SQL> with players (id, name) as
  2    (select 1, 'Mick'   from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Ffrank' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Sarah' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'Eva' from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Joe' from dual
  7    ),
  8  wins (id, player_won) as
  9    (select 1, 2 from dual union all
 10     select 2, 1 from dual union all
 11     select 3, 4 from dual union all
 12     select 4, 5 from dual union all
 13     select 5, 1 from dual
 14    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 15  select id from players
 16  minus
 17  select player_won from wins;

        ID
----------
         3

SQL>
```

So, yes ... player 3 didn't win any game so far.

Comment: Your query doesn't return all the players that didn't win a game; it only returns all the *ids* of the players (their id *and* name) that didn't win a game. To return the players you'd have to use your query as a subquery in a larger query.

Comment: Well, that's how I understood the question, @Bohemian. The OP didn't specify what *exactly* they want as the result, so I provided the ID.

Comment: @Littlefoot, as far as I understand, ```MINUS``` is not the best option because of full scan of both tables (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/em.920/a86647/vmqtune.htm). But it still works.

Comment: Certainly, it works, @John. It is up to optimizer whether it will (or will not) perform full table scan and whether it is (or is not) a drawback. For small tables, optimizer might not even *want* to use indexes. Documentation (link you posted) says: "... reducing the number of full table scans a clause **may require**" - therefore, full table scan may be required, or it may not be. It just depends. As of this very problem: as usual, there is more than just one "solution" to it. It is up to the OP to pick the one they find useful. It is actually great that people posted so many options.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should provide your attempts next time, but here you go:

```
select p.name
  from players p
 where not exists (select * from wins w where p.id = w.player_won);
```

`MINUS` is not the best option here because of not using indexes and instead performing a full-scan of both tables.

Answer (score 0):

> I've a data base with two tables.

You don't show the names or any definition of the tables, leaving me to make an educated guess about their structure.

> I tried but I don't know even how to begin.

What exactly *did* you try? Possibly what you are missing here is the concept of a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join).

---

Assuming the *tables* are named `player_table` and `wins_table`, and have column names exactly as you showed, *and* that the `player_won` column is intended to express the number of games won by the player of that row's ID, *and* without knowing whether or not `wins_table` will have rows for players with zero wins… this should cover it:

```sql
select Name
from players_table pt
left join wins_table wt on (pt.ID = wt.ID)
-- Either this player is explicitly specified to have Player_won=0
-- or there is no row for this player ID in the wins table
-- (but excluding the possibility of an explicit NULL value, since its meaning would be unclear)
where Player_won = 0 or wt.ID is null;
```

Comment: This will give an incorrect result if there is a play with `id` of `0` who has won a game.

Comment: @MT0, you and I clearly have a different interpretation of this (highly ambiguous) schema. My interpretation is that `Player_won` is the _number of games_ that the player of the given `ID` has won; yours is that `Player_won` is a FK to `Players.ID`, whereas `Wins.ID` means something else. We need clarification from the OP.

Comment: If that is your interpretation then using `NVL` still seems semantically wrong as `NULL` is an unknown amount and does not automatically mean `0`.

Comment: If we have one table mapping players' internet IDs to their names, and another mapping IDs to the number of games they have won, then it seems _reasonable_ to assume that the absence of a row in the second table means a player hasn't won any games. But yes, I agree with you in principle @MT0. The absence of any statement from the OP about the _meaning_ of the schema, and relationships between the tables, means there are several conflicting interpretations. A big waste of answerers’ time.

Comment: I am not talking about the absence of a row; I am talking about the presence of a row with a `NULL` value. You assume that a `NULL` value and a missing value both mean `0` wins and I disagree that if there is an explicit `NULL` value then it should not be treated as `0` wins and should be treated as an unknown number of wins; semantically, they are very different. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=971866cb0a0167b66b2494362c2a3655)

Comment: I agree with you on that. Again, if the OP wants us to interpret the schema in a particular way, rather than stab around in the dark trying to ascribe various _plausible_ ones with varying degrees of ambiguity…

Comment: Updated answer to exclude the case of an explicit NULL in the player_won column, @MT0

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the variety of answers you've gotten, there are many ways to accomplish this.

One additional way to do this is to use COUNT in a correlated subquery, as in:

```
SELECT *
  FROM PLAYERS p
  WHERE 0 = (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM WINS w
               WHERE w.PLAYER_WON = p.ID)
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2baac429e5c7058a42ea954b2f594376)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Players p 
INNER JOIN Wins w
ON p.ID = w.ID
WHERE w.players_won = 0
```

I have not done SQL in awhile but I think this might be right if you are looking for players with 0 wins

Comment: This assumes that a row exists in the `Wins` table for every player, even if that player has zero wins. If a corresponding row is not added to the `Wins` table until that player has >0 wins, then a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is needed instead, as I show in https://stackoverflow.com/a/72510331/20789